# Change thumbs on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, rotation, thumbnails

Have problem with this script, cant make it to continue rotate thumbs after last image

```
var cdn_url     = 'http://cdn.domain.com/';
var timers  = new Array;
var images  = new Array;
function changeThumb( id, cdn_url )
{
        document.getElementById(id).src = cdn_url;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img[id*='tmb_']").mouseover(function(){
        var image_id    = $(this).attr("id");
        var id_split    = image_id.split('_');
        var one    = id_split[1];
        var two    = id_split[2];
        thumbs = 10;

        for ( var i=0; i<=thumbs; i++   ) {
            var image_url = cdn_url + one + '/' + two + '/' + i + '.jpg';
            images[i]     = new Image();
            images[i].src = image_url;
        }
        for ( var i=0; i<=thumbs; i++ ) {
            timers[i] = setTimeout("changeThumb('" + image_id + "','" + cdn_url + one + '/' + two + '/' + i + '.jpg' + "')", i*200);
        }
    }).mouseout(function(){
        var image_id    = $(this).attr("id");
        var id_split    = image_id.split('_');
        var one    = id_split[1];
        var two    = id_split[2];
        var init = id_split[3];
        thumbs = 10;

        for ( var i=0; i<=thumbs; i++ ) {
            if ( typeof timers[i] == "number" ) {
                clearTimeout(timers[i]);
            }
        }
        $(this).attr('src', cdn_url + one + '/' + two + '/' + init + '.jpg');
    });
});
```

html

```
<img id="tmb_0613_2913374229_4" class="img"  src="http://cdn.domain.com/thumbs/0613/2913374229/4.jpg" />
```

Thumbs is rotating on hover but after last (10.jpg) wont start again from 0.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

Improvments include - compile images array once at load time, use interval instead of timeout, reference length of images array in for loop, start image loop where it last left off (optionally, continuous = true)

I ran it to make sure there are not console errors, but I don't have all of your html to check against...so let me know if it works for you.

Updated JS:

```
var cdn_url = 'http://telus-nezavisnost.com/videos/';
var thumbs  = 5;
var images = [];
var iterator = [];
var continuous = false;
var image_interval;
var init_thumb;

//global functions
var changeThumb = function(id, cdn_url){
    document.getElementById(id).src = cdn_url;
}

var initThumbs = function(selector){
    for ( var i=0; i<thumbs; i++  ) {
        var image_id    = selector.attr("id");
        var id_split    = image_id.split('_');
        var one    = id_split[1];
        var two    = id_split[2];
        var image_url = cdn_url + one + '/' + two + '/' + i + '.jpg';
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = image_url;
        if( images[image_id] === undefined ){
         images[image_id]        = [];
        }
        images[image_id][i]     = image;
    }
}

$(function() {
    $("img[id*='tmb_']").mouseover(function(){
        init_thumb = $(this).attr('src');
        initThumbs($(this));
        var image_id    = $(this).attr("id");
        var image_count = images[image_id].length;

        if( !(iterator.hasOwnProperty(image_id)) || !continuous ){
            iterator[image_id] = 1;
        }

        image_interval = setInterval(function(){
            changeThumb(image_id, images[image_id][iterator[image_id]].src);
            if( iterator[image_id] < ( image_count - 1 ) ){
                iterator[image_id]++;
            }else{
                iterator[image_id] = 1;   
            }
        }, 200);
    }).mouseout(function(){
        var image_id    = $(this).attr("id");
        clearInterval(image_interval);
        if( !continuous ){
            changeThumb(image_id, init_thumb);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmm there is error
`TypeError: images[image_id][iterator[image_id]] is undefined
 

changeThumb(image_id, images[image_id][iterator[image_id]].src);`

Comment: But also i think is not a good idea load all images when page is loaded, because i have there 50+ thumbs this will be 50*10 = 500 images loaded and once

Comment: it doesn't load them all. it just saves the paths to the images array.

Comment: if you post up your entire html i'll check out the type error

Comment: actually, i see that error. It's because the image never gets found. are you sure all the images you are referencing exist?

Comment: also, i forgot we were preloading here. it's probably still better to pre load them once at the beginning anyway. what's the point of preloading if you're not "preloading" until the user asks for the images? kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Here is demo http://jsfiddle.net/6v9Zd/6/ and also html `<a href="#">     
    <img id="tmb_069_565658_2" width="240" src="http://telus-nezavisnost.com/videos/069/565658/2.jpg" />
</a>`

Comment: Yes this is working but problem is still because when you open page all images is loaded `481 requests` i have now on site 6MB size..

Comment: updated fiddle to initThumbs for current mouseover element only. http://jsfiddle.net/6v9Zd/24/

Comment: heh yes this one is working only one problem is still on mouseout should be back default thumbs this is what im define in example above `var init = id_split[3];`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6v9Zd/37/ works. fyi, if you want the thumbs to loop continuously instead of reseting on mouseout, just set continuous = true

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37060/discussion-between-eric-uldall-and-milan-milosevic)